# Working with two dictionaries in one pickle file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pickle

I would like to make this very clear so ill start off with the case i know so everyone knows exactly what i mean. When i'm storing just a single dictionary in a pickle file this is the method i use and it works great.

```
#open pickle file
with open("a_pickle_file", 'rb') as input:
  x = pickle.load(input)
#Now update the dict in your pickle file 
a_dict.update(x)
```

Assume some arbitrary manipulation to this dictionary now i save like so:

```
#Save whatever u added to the dict
pickle.dump(open(a_dict,"a_pickle_file"))
```

Now moving on to the case that im unsure about and which seems to have little to no documentation from what i've found anyway. I want to do the same exact thing as above only this time i will be storing two dictionaries inside a list and then storing the list in the pickle file like so,

```
#Two dict
MyFirstDict = { 1: 'a' }
MySecondDict = { 2:'b' }

#Store them in a list
two_dict = [MyFirstDict, MySecondDict]

#save them 
pkl.dump( two_dict, open( "two_dict_pkl_file", "wb" ) )
```

Now i have a two dictionaries inside a list and its stored in my pickle file. Now from here how does one load this pickle file for manipulation? Once it is loaded how can i access each dictionary inside for updating and manipulation. Finally, can i just use the same `pkl.dump` statement above to re-save it. Thanks

**EDIT**

So for the most part the procedure is generally the same when doing this except for the part where you need to update your dictionaries with previous info. This is the output of a list of two dict in one pkl file:

```
[{'I': 'D', 'x': 'k', 'k': [datetime.time(11, 52, 3, 514000)]}, {'I': 'D', 'x': 'k', 'D': [datetime.time(11, 52, 3, 514000)]}]
```

As you can see it is stored oddly, and i can't seem to properly access each dict separately for updating their must be some syntax to properly do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it a try! Do pickle.load() and you'll see a list with two dicts in it. You can reference them in several ways, but this is a common way to do it:

```
MyFirstDict, MySecondDict = pickle.load(open("two_dict_pkl_file", "rb"))
```

And yes, you can just pickle.dump them again if you want to overwrite the existing contents.

**EDIT**

Here is a script illustrating the concept:

```
import pickle, datetime

test_file = "two_dict_pkl_file"

# store two dicts in a list
MyFirstDict = { 1: 'a' }
MySecondDict = { 2:'b' }
two_dict = [MyFirstDict, MySecondDict]

print "first pickle test"
print "this python list gets pickled:"
print two_dict
print
print "this is the pickle file"
pickle.dump( two_dict, open( test_file, "wb" ) )
print open(test_file, "rb").read()
print

print "update pickle test"
pickle_list = pickle.load(open(test_file, "rb"))
print "this python object is read back:"
print pickle_list
print
d1, d2 = pickle_list
two_dict = [d1, d2]
d1['time'] = d2['time'] = datetime.datetime.now().time()
pickle.dump( two_dict, open( test_file, "wb" ) )
print "this is the updated pickle:"
print open(test_file, "rb").read()
print

print "and this is the updated python:"
print pickle.load(open(test_file, "rb"))
```

...and its output

```
first pickle test
this python list gets pickled:
[{1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}]

this is the pickle file
(lp0
(dp1
I1
S'a'
p2
sa(dp3
I2
S'b'
p4
sa.

update pickle test
this python object is read back:
[{1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}]

this is the updated pickle:
(lp0
(dp1
I1
S'a'
p2
sS'time'
p3
cdatetime
time
p4
(S'\n2;\x02s\x95'
p5
tp6
Rp7
sa(dp8
I2
S'b'
p9
sg3
g7
sa.

and this is the updated python:
[{1: 'a', 'time': datetime.time(10, 50, 59, 160661)}, {2: 'b', 'time': datetime.time(10, 50, 59, 160661)}]
```

Comment: So i took your advice and just gave it a try and iv'e figured everything out besides the updating part. Things here are different then just having a single dictionary stored see edit for the output.

Comment: Looking at your edit, that's python source code, not a pickle file. If this is the result of `print pickle.load(...)` then that's exactly what you want - two dicts inside a list. I'm adding a test script for more details.

Comment: I'm giving it a try now, but why doesn't your final line have the updated info in it? I was under the impression i had to use `.update` to update the dictionaries.

Comment: My bad, I was adding print statements and accidentally deleted the line where two_list is reassigned. I've supplied an edit.

Comment: ...and dict.update() is only used if you want to update a dict with the contents of another dict. If you just want to change individual entries, `mydict[somekey] = someval` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, i need to update the dictionary. I need it to have the information already stored in it plus the added information saved. It works but still it is not updating the information its just over writing it. I need to do exactly what i have in my first example.

Comment: I think you made some edits, i have work but when i get home tonight ill be sure to try it again and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for the time and effort i really appreciate it, this worked perfect and it makes sense i just wasn't thinking about the problem correctly. Thanks again man.